# Creating/Generating Several Sections (Including \section Command) from a List

Tags: macros, lists, environments, tcolorbox

Is there a possibility of having a list of terms that will be used to create several consecutive sections to facilitate the organization of the document?

I'm pasting section by section and renaming one section at a time to get all sections, but there are many sections for me to create...

The following figure shows the sections I want to create...

[image]

The list would be this:

```
Inferface do usuário
Aba - Recursos
Mouse
Árvore de projeto
Instant 3D
Orientação de vistas
Estilos de exibição
Ocultar/Exibir itens
Reconstruir
Planos
```

I hope I was objective and clear ...

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{titlesec}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Conhecendo o SolidWorks}

\section{Interface do Usuário}

\tcbsidebyside[title=Interface do Usuário,
sidebyside adapt=left,
bicolor,colback=white,colbacklower=yellow!10,
fonttitle=\bfseries,center title,drop lifted shadow,
]{%
    \includegraphics[height=4cm]{Envolver.png}
    %
}{%
    Esse recurso envolve um esboço em uma face plana ou não-plana. Você pode criar uma face plana a partir de modelos cilíndricos, cônicos ou extrudados. Também é possível selecionar um perfil plano para adicionar vários esboços de spline fechados. O recurso Envolver oferece seleção de contorno e reutilização de esboço.
}

\section{Aba - Recursos}

\tcbsidebyside[title=Aba - Recursos,
sidebyside adapt=left,
bicolor,colback=white,colbacklower=yellow!10,
fonttitle=\bfseries,center title,drop lifted shadow,
]{%
    \includegraphics[height=4cm]{Envolver.png}
    %
}{%
    Esse recurso envolve um esboço em uma face plana ou não-plana. Você pode criar uma face plana a partir de modelos cilíndricos, cônicos ou extrudados. Também é possível selecionar um perfil plano para adicionar vários esboços de spline fechados. O recurso Envolver oferece seleção de contorno e reutilização de esboço.
}

\end{document}
```

**Envolver.png**

[image]

The result would be something like this...

[image]

**EDIT**

In all sections, the images will be different and the texts in the second column will also be different.

Comment: Maybe this is rather a **perl** or **python** (scripting language) problem/task than a LaTeX issue?! I proposed a change of the title of the question, reverse it if you are not happy with it.

Answer (score 3):

This uses `expl3` (loaded by `xparse`) and provides a `\seq` variable that is populated with `\PopulateSectionSequence` and displayed later with `\DisplaySectionSequence`.

The 'syntax' is

```
\PopulateSectionSequence{
   {Section Title; Section description}, 
   {Other section title; other section description}
}
```

Use `;` to separate title and description, use `{}` to prevent `,` being interpreted as a splitter of the several entries. Use `{;}` to keep `;` as a literal input, if needed.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{titlesec}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xparse}

\tcbset{sidebysideboxoptions/.style={
  sidebyside adapt=left,
  bicolor,colback=white,colbacklower=yellow!10,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,center title,drop lifted shadow,
}}



\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_lcarvalho_section_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\PopulateSectionSequence}{+m}{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_lcarvalho_section_seq {#1} 
}



\NewDocumentCommand{\DisplaySectionSequence}{}{%
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_lcarvalho_section_seq {%
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {;} {##1}
    \section{\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1}}
    \tcbsidebyside[
    title=\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1},
    sidebysideboxoptions]{%
      \includegraphics[height=4cm]{Envolver.png}
    }{
      \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {2}
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Conhecendo o SolidWorks}


\PopulateSectionSequence{%
  {Interface do Usuário; Esse recurso envolve um esboço em uma face plana ou não-plana. Você pode criar uma face plana a partir de modelos cilíndricos, cônicos ou extrudados. Também é possível selecionar um perfil plano para adicionar vários esboços de spline fechados. O recurso Envolver oferece seleção de contorno e reutilização de esboço.},
  {Aba - Recursos;
    Esse recurso envolve um esboço em uma face plana ou não-plana. Você pode criar uma face plana a partir de modelos cilíndricos, cônicos ou extrudados. Também é possível selecionar um perfil plano para adicionar vários esboços de spline fechados. O recurso Envolver oferece seleção de contorno e reutilização de esboço.},
  {Mouse; Mouse informations},
  {Árvore de projeto ; Projeto\dots},
{Instant 3D; Something about 3D},
{Orientação de vistas ; Vista content},
{Estilos de exibição ; Foo },
{Ocultar/Exibir itens ; Foobar},
{Reconstruir ; Reconstruction},
{Planos ; Plans(?)}
}


\DisplaySectionSequence

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Andrew: (+1 for your solution as well)... Well, `expl3` has an awful syntax, but it is very powerful

Comment: Yes, I agree, and many idiosyncratic commands as well but, as you say, really powerful -- and syntax aside quite elegant. I really like your code!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I still can not test, but does it work by varying the images?

Comment: @LCarvalho Just add the image after a `;` in `\PopulateSectionSequence` and then replace `Envolver.png` with `\l_tmpa_seq {3}` in the definition of `\DisplaySectionSequence`.

Comment: @LCarvalho: it was not clear that the image should change with each section as well, but Andrews proposition is correct

Answer (score 3):

It really depends what the content of these "sections" is. In your MWE they have the same image and the same text, which seems unlikely in general. If this is what you actually want then just define a command to construct your "sections" and loop through the titles using, for examnple, `\foreach` from the [pgffor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgffor) package, to produce your document. Doing it this way, here is part of page 2:

[image]

(I have used the [mwe](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) package for the image.) Here is the code for generating this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{titlesec}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newcommand\Section[1]{%
\section{#1}
\tcbsidebyside[title=#1,
    sidebyside adapt=left,
    bicolor,colback=white,colbacklower=yellow!10,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,center title,drop lifted shadow,
  ]{%
      \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image}
      %
  }{%
    Esse recurso envolve um esboço em uma face plana ou não-plana. Você
    pode criar uma face plana a partir de modelos cilíndricos, cônicos
    ou extrudados. Também é possível selecionar um perfil plano para
    adicionar vários esboços de spline fechados. O recurso Envolver
    oferece seleção de contorno e reutilização de esboço.
  }
}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Conhecendo o SolidWorks}

\foreach \ttle in { Inferface do usuário,
                    Aba - Recursos,
                    Mouse,
                    Árvore de projeto,
                    Instant 3D,
                    Orientação de vistas,
                    Estilos de exibição,
                    Ocultar/Exibir itens,
                    Reconstruir,
                    Planos } { \Section{\ttle} }

\end{document}
```

In practice, your title, image and the text will almost certainly change with each section. As the text is likely to be at least paragraph size I would instead define an environment to construct the images. Since you need to pass the text of the section to `\tcbsidebyside` it will be slightly easier if you use the [environ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) package to construct the environment as this lets you work with the `\BODY` of the environment directly. He is a modified version of your MWE that implements this approach. The output is similar.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{titlesec}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{mwe}

\NewEnviron{Section}[2]{%
  % \begin{Section}{title}{image} ...text...\end{Section}
  \section{#1}
  \tcbsidebyside[title=#1,
      sidebyside adapt=left,
      bicolor,colback=white,colbacklower=yellow!10,
      fonttitle=\bfseries,center title,drop lifted shadow,
    ]{%
        \includegraphics[height=4cm]{#2}
        %
    }{\BODY}
}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Conhecendo o SolidWorks}

\begin{Section}{Inferface do usuário}{example-image-a}
    Esse recurso envolve um esboço em uma face plana ou não-plana. Você
    pode criar uma face plana a partir de modelos cilíndricos, cônicos
    ou extrudados. Também é possível selecionar um perfil plano para
    adicionar vários esboços de spline fechados. O recurso Envolver
    oferece seleção de contorno e reutilização de esboço.
\end{Section}

\begin{Section}{Aba - Recursos}{example-image-b}
   \lipsum[1]
\end{Section}

\begin{Section}{Árvore de projeto}{example-image-c}
    \lipsum[3]
\end{Section}

\end{document}
```